# How to publish a packaged jar as release in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Then I run the following job in `gitlab-ci`, then click on the "Deployments > Releases" tab, the projects' source code is packaged, **BUT my build *.jar is missing.**

What I want: the final jar, and optionally remove the sources. Only publish the packaged jar. But how?

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean package

release:
  stage: release
  needs:
    - job: build
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - mv target/*.jar project.jar
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - project.jar
  release:
    name: 'Awesome Project'
    description: 'Awesome description'
    tag_name: 'Awesome'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike in GitHub, GitLab releases don't allow you to upload binaries or other assets directly. Instead, you can add *links* to your releases, which point to a location in which the asset can be downloaded. You can potentially use one of GitLab's package registries or the generic registry as one builtin option.

GitLab provides [one example using the generic registry](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli/-/tree/master/docs/examples/release-assets-as-generic-package) with release-cli.

So, you will need to decide on where you will upload your assets, then you can use the [`release:assets:links:` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#releaseassetslinks) (or release-cli) to add the links.

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn clean package

release:
  stage: release
  variables:
    UPLOAD_URL: "You implement this"
  needs:
    - job: build
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - mv target/*.jar project.jar
    - make upload project.jar "${UPLOAD_URL}" # you implement this

  release:
    name: 'Awesome Project'
    description: 'Awesome description'
    tag_name: 'Awesome'
    assets:
      links:
        - name: project.jar
          url: $UPLOAD_URL
```

Technically, you might be able to use artifacts and the [API URL for downloading artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#download-a-single-artifact-file-by-job-id), but keep in mind that this has several drawbacks that may make it unsuitable for most use cases, including:

1. To use the link, you'll need to have permissions to download job artifacts from the project
2. Artifacts typically expire after some time
3. Artifact storage counts towards your project's storage quotas

```
# ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - project.jar
    expire_in: never  # prevent expiration

  release:
    name: 'Awesome Project'
    description: 'Awesome description'
    tag_name: 'Awesome'
    assets:
      links: # use artifact download link
        - name: project.jar
          url: "$CI_API_V4_URL/projects/$CI_PROJECT_ID/jobs/$CI_JOB_ID/artifacts/project.jar"
```